# Comparison between Snyk and Sonarcloud/SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonarcloud, snyk, devsecops

I need to do a comparison between the features and functionality of Snyk and Sonarcloud/Sonarqube and the only thing I can find is a speed comparison:

https://snyk.io/blog/sast-tools-speed-comparison-snyk-code-sonarqube-lgtm/

....does anyone know if there are any comparison of features and functionality between two? If so, please can you let me know where to look?

thanks very much in advance for any help with this.

Comment: I found this https://www.peerspot.com/products/comparisons/snyk_vs_sonarqube

Comment: Did you found a SOLID answer for this question dear questioner?

Comment: What are you looking for, only SAST? Snyk is much more than just SAST, it does SCA, Container Image Scanning, IaC scans and more. I don't think there is any detailed list out there that lists any single feature compared in a table. [Disclaimer: I'm a Solutions Engineer at Snyk]

Answer (score 5):

We have made comparisons and benchmarks at Snyk.
The short answer is simple:

- Sonarqube is focused on Code Quality and is fairly good at that. But the security scan is an add on and very limited (in language supported, in rule coverage, amount of false positive) and rarely considered as a SAST tool
- Snyk does not support quality (just some rules in IDE) but heavily focused on security. With fast scans, accuracy, depth in the number of CVEs covered for SAST and wide language coverage. Plus, Snyk has a strong SCA support.
  Hope that helps.

I personally ran a comparison on this repo: https://github.com/OWASP-Benchmark/BenchmarkJava and the results are clear.
Hope that helps.

Comment: disclaimer: I work at Snyk, to remove ambiguity. But feel free to reach out I can share the 2 scans results

Comment: I would really like to see those results.

Comment: I don't see how I can share a screenshot here but some of the results we had when running comparisons on the specific repo above:
Command Injection: Snyk 168 findings, SQ 0 findings
Path Traversal (complex to catch): Snyk 268 finsings, SQ 0 findings (they may not have a rule for that)
Secure Cookie Flag: 30 vs 0
basically the security rules are very limited in Sonarqube
They did find XSS, SQLi and weak cryptography

Comment: @JonathanGruber If you're inclined to, you can add an image to your answer. (but not comments)